# Getting Activity Results from MX Player

Tags: java, android

I'm parsing a live stream uri to mx player and i want to get the results and see if the streaming uri was working or not. ( when uri doesn't work, mx player given an error can't play video ) . Here is my code. I've read MX Player API documentation but couldn't grab how to analyze the onactivityresults.

```
Uri localUri = Uri.parse(link);
            Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            localIntent.setData(localUri);
            localIntent.putExtra("decode_mode", (byte) 0);
            localIntent.putExtra("fast_mode", true);
            localIntent.putExtra("secure_uri", true);
            localIntent.putExtra("title", name);
            localIntent.putExtra("position", 10000);
            localIntent.putExtra("return_result", true);
            try {
                localIntent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro");
                startActivityForResult(localIntent, 0);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException localActivityNotFoundException1) {
                try {
                    localIntent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
                    startActivityForResult(localIntent, 0);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException localActivityNotFoundException2) {
//Toast MX player is not installed
                }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(ChannelList.this, "Results Returned",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First I also encountered the same problem in the beginning. I always got back data=null in onActivityResult.

Then I found a good example here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/GvbDy9jMGzI

Also it's a good idea to read through result descrption on the official page https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api

My code works just fine on Android 4.4.4 with MXPlayer 1.8.15.

The calling part:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
intent.setClassName("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad", "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad.ActivityScreen");
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(cur_material.video_url);
intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "application/x-mpegURL");
intent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad"); // com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro
intent.putExtra("return_result", true);
//startActivity(intent);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The receiving part:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)  // -1 RESULT_OK : Playback was completed or stopped by user request.
    //Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: User canceled before starting any playback. 
    //RESULT_ERROR (=Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER): Last playback was ended with an error.

    if (data.getAction().equals("com.mxtech.intent.result.VIEW")) {
        //data.getData()
        int pos = data.getIntExtra("position", -1); // Last playback position in milliseconds. This extra will not exist if playback is completed.
        int dur = data.getIntExtra("duration", -1); // Duration of last played video in milliseconds. This extra will not exist if playback is completed.
        String cause = data.getStringExtra("end_by"); //  Indicates reason of activity closure.
```